# How does robots.txt work with sites in subfolders?

Tags: seo, search-engines, web-crawlers, robots.txt, access-control

I have a single web host with a number of other parked domains/sites in sub-directories, like this:

`example.com` is the primary site and root directory of the web hosting.

`example.com/www.example2.com` is one of the parked sites, but it is just a subfolder of the primary site.

Both `www.example2.com` and `www.example.com/www.example2.com` are accessible as the same content, but I want to block access the later while allowing access to the former.

**Will a robots.txt file in the primary site disallowing www.* allow `www.example2.com` to be crawled?**

Comment: This is not a good configuration scheme, in fact, it is horrible. No site should reside inside of another. You should really fix this. That said, *Will a robots.txt file in the primary site disallowing www. allow www.example2.com to be crawled?* Short answer? No. Robots.txt ***must always*** be in the root directory of a site. No exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is a robots.txt entry like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /www.example2.com
```

Let's suggestion you have more than 100 'parked' exampleNR.com URLs, but don't want to write a line for every single one of them...use this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /www.example
```

The problem is, it actually is **not officially supported**, but many robots like Googlebot are able to understand those easy wildcards. RegEx are definitely not supported. [for additonal information](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

**UPDATE**

Deleted the trailing asterisk since robots.txt uses simple prefix matching anyway. Thanks for your attention, [w3dk](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1243/w3dk)

Comment: In your second example, there is no need for a wildcard `*` on the end of the URL-path since `robots.txt` uses simple prefix matching anyway. This "prefix matching" allows your first example to block `/www.example2.com/path/to/file`. All that would seem to be required is a `Disallow: /www.` directive in the `robots.txt` file for the primary domain (ie. `example.com/robots.txt`).

Answer (score -1):

From what you are saying if everything is redirected to example.com then yes.

Comment: Can you please explain more - a one line answer is rarely sufficient. Whilst the answer is _approximately_ "yes", nothing is strictly being "redirected" (although you are using this as a very lose term). The OPs suggestion of what to put in the `robots.txt` file is also unclear, so could be clarified in your answer.